# Beta distribution, finding $\alpha, \beta$

Tags: arithmetic

Here the expected value and the variance are given, and it's needed to find the values of $\alpha,\beta$.

From the Beta distribution and the elicited prior information, we can write:

$E(\theta)={\alpha\over{\alpha+\beta}}=0.1$

${Var(\theta)}={{\alpha\beta}\over{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}}=(0.054)^2=0.0029$

We can write

${{\alpha\beta}\over{(\alpha+\beta)^2}}={\alpha\over{(\alpha+\beta)}}\times{\beta\over{\alpha+\beta}}=0.1\times(1-0.1)=0.09$

I don't follow the line beneath *We can write*. Why should it be that $\frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta}$ is $(1 - 0.1)$ here? I'm sure there's a fact relating to this that I'm not aware of.

---

## edit

This can be seen from the following

$$
\frac{
\alpha + \beta
}{
\alpha + \beta} = 1
$$

as pointed out below in a comment.

Comment: Use $$\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha+\beta}=1.$$

Comment: If you feel that you know the answer to your question, you can write a complete answer in the Answer box below your question.

Comment: @Sycorax seems like noticing that algebra was enough thanks, I've not really anything else to add to it. Unless I just wrote that, but just writing the edit seems like it would be a bit lazy

Comment: Some questions have short answers. The purpose of this website is to cultivate create clear questions with clear answers. Right now, this question counts as "unanswered" because there are no answers to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments, we can infer that the key detail to OP is observing that $\frac{\alpha + \beta}{\alpha + \beta} = 1$, which holds in this case because we are restricted to considering $\alpha > 0$ and $\beta > 0$ (by the definition of the beta distribution), whence the rest is just tedious algebra.

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(\theta)
&= \frac{\alpha \beta}{(\alpha + \beta)^2 (\alpha + \beta + 1)}  \\
&=
\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} \cdot \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} \cdot \frac{1}{\alpha + \beta + 1} \\
&= \mathbb{E}(\theta) \cdot \left(1 - \mathbb{E}(\theta)\right)
\cdot \frac{1}{\alpha + \beta + 1} \\
&= 0.1 \cdot 0.9 \cdot \frac{1}{\alpha + \beta + 1} \\
0.002916 &= 0.09 \cdot \frac{1}{\alpha + \beta + 1} \\
29.8642 &=\alpha + \beta
\end{align} 
$$

And from there the values of $\alpha, \beta$ are obtained by solving for the given value of the expectation.